# Git files corrupted 50% of the time when shutting down

Tags: windows-10, ssd, external-hard-drive, git, usb-flash-drive

My git files are 50% of the time corrupted for no reason. I have no idea why, and hope one of you knows how to solve this.

I currently have a External SSD (Samsung T5, connected via USB, being seen as SCSI device) formatted to exFAT. If I work on my laptop, do push and pull some things, then close GitHub and shutdown, 50% of the time, whenever I connect the SSD to my PC, the git files in the .git folder are corrupted.

I found out that this can be resolved by changing the drive's policy from `Quick removal` to `Better performance`, but that resolved in a problem that I cannot eject my drive, so that's a no-go.

As the git files are corrupt, I have no way to delete them other than `CHKDSK F:\ /F`, which also removes some random files often, so that's also a no-go.

Anyone any idea how I can resolve this matter?

Comment: "this can be resolved by changing the drive's policy from Quick removal to Better performance". Hmm, that's surprising. I would have expected the other way around as quick removal should disable disk caching ...

Comment: [Do You Really Need to Safely Remove USB Flash Drives?](https://www.howtogeek.com/118546/htg-explains-do-you-really-need-to-safely-remove-usb-sticks/) is worth a read.

Comment: Either way, the USB drive should be safe to remove if you completely shutdown the laptop. Are you doing a full shutdown? A hybrid shutdown? A sleep? A hibernate?

Comment: @DavidPostill I know, but it somehow "does it's job better" according to a lot of folks on SO. It is not per se a USB drive. It is indeed connected via USB, but it's a SCSI device according to Windows. I don't know if this has anything to do with it's behaviour, will add it in the question. I close all open programs, then hit shutdown, so it is a full shutdown.

Comment: It looks like a bus powered drive. Could be that the drive itself has some caches that are not being flushed quickly enough while Windows is shutting down. Does it work fine if you do a safe eject?

Comment: If you are using Windows 10 and you have not disabled fastboot then you are not doing a "full" shutdown. By default since Windows 8 "shutdown" does a hybrid shutdown where it closes your apps and then hibernates your computer. You can disable the fastboot in the power options and see if the problem persists... another question arises... do you find this corruption on moving the drive to another computer, or on this same computer after it has booted again? Do you remove the drive from the computer at any point before turning that computer back on again?

Comment: I will try to look into that! I find it corrupted when I shutdown the laptop, remove the drive and connect it to my PC.

Comment: @MarkD Then that would be the problem, before taking it to another PC you *must* eject it, booting your laptop if needs be, or otherwise you need to disable fastboot in Windows so that it does a "normal" shutdown.